# In Windows Powershell, how can I wait for an event to be true before proceeding?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm writing a Windows Powershell script that stops a service, then I want to print the service's status when it's finally stopped. I've tried the following, but it just hangs

```
$service = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*MyService*"}
Stop-Service -Name $service.name
$wait=true
while ($wait) {
  if($service.Status -eq "Running") {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
  }
  else {
    $wait=$false
  }
}
```

I know I can probably write a `for{}` loop instead that counts 0-9, and breaks when my condition is met, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tanstaafl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71343861/45375) addresses your immediate problem:

- The `.Status` property value of a [`[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller) instance (as returned by [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service)) is a *static* value that only reflects the status of the service *at the time of the `Get-Service` call*.<sup>[1]</sup>
- To update the value to reflect the then-current status, call the `.Refresh()` method.

However, there is no need to explicitly wait for a service to stop, because [`Stop-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service) is *synchronous*, i.e.:

- It *waits* for the service to finish stopping before returning, unless you explicitly pass `-NoWait`.
- If that doesn't happen within a fixed, 2-second timeout:<sup>[2]</sup>

  - A *warning* is issued if the service last reported that stopping is *pending* - potentially, stopping will *eventually* finish.
  - Otherwise, a *non-terminating error* occurs - this suggests that the service is stuck.

Thus, you can simplify your code as follows:

```
# Report a script-terminating error if stopping doesn't finish
# within the timeout period.
Stop-Service -Name *MyService* -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction Stop
```

More work is needed if you want to implement a retry mechanism.

---

<sup>[1] There is one exception, although the behavior is undocumented and should be considered an implementation detail: If you *pipe* a *preexisting* `ServiceController` instance to `Stop-Service` / `Start-Service`, these cmdlets refresh the instance for you; e.g., after executing `($service = Get-Service Bits) | Stop-Service`, `$service.Status` *is* current (reflects `Stopped`).</sup>

<sup>[2] As of PowerShell Core 7.3.0-preview.2 - see [the source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/102782fbb0bc82310ca8eaba5574fc54e9ca9e6d/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/Service.cs#L856).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-check your service within the loop.

```
$service = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*MyService*"}
Stop-Service -Name $service.name
$wait=true
while ($wait) {
  if($service.Status -eq "Running") {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    # ADD THIS BELOW. Need to re-check service in loop.
    $service = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*MyService*"}
  }
  else {
    $wait=$false
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent point, but you don't need to call `Get-Service` again: you can refresh the status of the existing `$service` object with `$service.Refresh()`